# Can python-igraph be used for min s-t cut?

Tags: python, graph, igraph

Can Python-igraph be used to do min s-t cut?

I want the minimum cost cut that cuts the designated source and sink nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.

```
from igraph import Graph
from random import randint
g = Graph.GRG(100, 0.2)        # generate a geometric random graph
g.es["capacity"] = [randint(0, 1000) for i in xrange(g.ecount())]
cut = g.maxflow(0, 99, "capacity")
```

cut.membership then gives you the membership of each vertex (0-1 vector), cut[0] gives you the vertices on one side of the cut, cut[1] gives the other, cut.value gives the value of the cut.

[all credit goes to @Tamás]